# Linear Combinations: Is it possible for number of vectors to outnumber vector dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

In linear algebra. Just learned about linear combinations, and solved the following using gaussian elimination:
$$c1\begin{bmatrix} 1  \\\ -2  \\\ -5  \end{bmatrix} + c2\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\\ 5 \\\ 6 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}7\\\ 4\\\ -3 \end{bmatrix}$$
This  case made total sense to me. We created an augmented matrix and solved.

However, I was thinking what if our combo had been longer? What if there were 4 scalars that we were trying to solve for, but the vectors still were only 3 dimensional? Is something like this possible?
$$c1\begin{bmatrix} 1  \\\ -2  \\\ -5  \end{bmatrix} + c2\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\\ 5 \\\ 6 \end{bmatrix} + c3 \begin{bmatrix}7\\\ 4\\\ -3 \end{bmatrix} + c4 \begin{bmatrix}7\\\ 4\\\ -3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}randomint\\\ randomint\\\ randomint \end{bmatrix}$$

In my feeble understanding, this is not possible. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes; but in this case, the choices of coefficients need not be unique.

Comment: Try it. You know about Gaussian elimination, so what happens when you run that algorithm on this system?